# can i get image file width and height from uri in android?

Tags: android, image, height, width, uri

i can getting the image width through `MediaStore.Images.Media` normally

but i need to getting the image width and height from image which selected from dropbox

so currently i have following method to getting image size from dropbox

```
private void getDropboxIMGSize(Uri uri){
    String size = Long.toString(new File(uri.getPath()).length());
    return size;
}
```

but what i actually need are getting the file width and height value

anyone know how to achieve that?please help!

Answer (score 120, accepted):

```
private void getDropboxIMGSize(Uri uri){
   BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
   options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
   BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File(uri.getPath()).getAbsolutePath(), options);
   int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
   int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
 
}
```

no there is no way. You have to create a Bitmap object. if you use the `inJustDecodeBounds` flag the bitmap would not be loaded in memory. In fact `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` will return null. In my example `uri` is the phisical path to the image

Comment: will this way cause oom fc? no need to set to null/recycling after getting width and height?

Comment: no . Since the bitmap will be not loaded in memory it will not cause OOM neither you need to recycle it.

Comment: but i getting width and height is 0 at logcat?

Comment: You have access to the phisical image?

Comment: I just chosen a jpeg image

Comment: yes,i also found that dropbox uri are start with file:// and gallery image start with content://

Comment: imageHeight and imageWidth are zero? Sounds strange. Can you check the image size with a file expolorer?

Comment: it's odds,I can see the file path in logcat,but I can't find the file in file explorer,search /data /sdcard and internal memory /data

Comment: good :). I will update my answer with the modification you provide in yours

Comment: @blackbelt I propose please edit your sample code with regards to jkjk's answer.

Comment: @hasanghaforian thanks for the input. The OP does not want the file size. What he needs is: `i need to get the image width and height`

Comment: @blackbelt Ok! But I mean please change `decodeFile(uri.getPath()).getAbsolutePath(),`  to `decodeFile(new File(uri.getPath()).getAbsolutePath(),`

Comment: This is not a solution, since Uris may not be actually files.

Comment: It was at the time the answer was written Christian.

Comment: I don't know why, but it returns width and height 0

Comment: I am getting 0 height and 0 width using this solution

Comment: Hi, how does decodeFile get the dimensions? Are they from the meta-data or are they from really decoding the image data? Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

Blackbelt's answer is correct if you have a file uri. However, if you are using the new file providers as in the [official camera tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html), it won't work. This works for that case:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
        getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(mPhotoUri),
        null,
        options);
int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It is able to get height width of `content://media/external/images/media/272`. However, the height and width is reverted (imageHeight = actual width and imageWidth = actual height). Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: @h8pathak I'm not up to date on this stuff anymore. Feel free to edit it, or comment the exact code and I'll edit it.

Comment: This works but is very slow. Using ExifInterface is much faster

Answer (score 16):

Blackbelt's answer will work most of the time using `Options`, but I would like to propose another solution or fallback solution by using the `ExifInterface`.  If you have the image URI, you can create the `ExifInterface` using the full path, no need for Bitmap object nor `BitmapFactory.Options`.

ex.

```
int width = exif.getAttributeInt( ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_WIDTH, defaultValue );
int height = exif.getAttributeInt( ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_LENGTH, defaultValue );
```

Comment: this solution only works for Android API 23 and above

Answer (score 3):

the solution is use `new File(uri.getPath()).getAbsolutePath()` instead of `uri.toString()`

Comment: This is not a solution, since Uris may not be actually files.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer returns with me a 0 of width/height, by replacing uri.getPath() with uri.getLastPathSegment(), it returns the correct dimensions

```
public static int[] getImageDimension(Uri uri){
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File(uri.getLastPathSegment()).getAbsolutePath(), options);
    return new int[]{options.outWidth, options.outHeight};
}
```

Comment: This still returns 0 for width and height.

Answer (score 3):

For folks having content uri (starting with `content://`), open an `InputStream` & decode that stream to avoid getting 0 width and height. I'll use Kotlin

```
val uri: Uri = ....

val options = BitmapFactory.Options().apply { inJustDecodeBounds = true }
val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options)

val width = options.outWidth
val height = options.outHeight
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Blackbelt answer you should use the following code to retrieve file path from Uri:

```
public static String getPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT &&
            DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, contentUri)) {
        return getPathForV19AndUp(context, contentUri);
    } else {
        return getPathForPreV19(context, contentUri);
    }
}

private static String getPathForPreV19(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        try {
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            return cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    return null;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
private static String getPathForV19AndUp(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    String documentId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(contentUri);
    String id = documentId.split(":")[1];

    String[] column = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().
            query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    column, sel, new String[]{ id }, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        try {
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use InputStream:

```
public int[] getImageSize(Uri uri){
    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        InputStream input = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, options);  input.close();
        return new int[]{options.outWidth, options.outHeight};
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
    return new int[]{0,0};
}
```

It'll return in array form:

```
int[]{ width , height }
```

Comment: one answer that solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

This is a concrete working example of the `ExifInterface` [solution proposed by @simplatek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34889691/10259491), using an extension function on the `Uri` type:

```
fun Uri.getImageDimensions(context: Context): Pair<Int, Int> {
    val inputStream = context.contentResolver.openInputStream(this)!!
    val exif = ExifInterface(inputStream)

    val width = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_WIDTH, defaultValue)
    val height = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_LENGTH, defaultValue)

    return Pair(width, height)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you guys keep getting (0,0) in the width and height, you probably want to decode a stream, and not a file.

It probably because you're trying to read an image from the assets. Try this:

```
val b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.assets.open("path/in/assets/img.png"))
val width = b.width
val height = b.height
```

Answer (score 0):

If you struggle with getting reverted dimensions - width and height taking place each other - for portrait images, this is an extended solution:

```
private fun getImageSize(uri: Uri): Size {
    var input = activity?.contentResolver?.openInputStream(uri)!!
    val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, options)

    input = activity?.contentResolver?.openInputStream(uri)!!

    var orientation = ExifInterface(input).getAttribute(TAG_ORIENTATION)?.toInt()
    if (orientation == null) {
        orientation = ORIENTATION_NORMAL
    }
    if (orientation == ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90 || orientation == ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
        val outWidth = options.outWidth
        val outHeight = options.outHeight
        options.outWidth = outHeight
        options.outHeight = outWidth
    }

    return Size(options.outWidth, options.outHeight)
}
```

An important point is that decodeStream closes the inputStream when finishes its job. So it is required to be opened again to be able to get orientation from ExifInterface.

By the way, ExifInterface comes from `androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:x.x.x`