# Get Image Width and Height from URI

Tags: android

Is it possible to get the width and height of a image file from its URI.  I was trying to use this code but theirs a error:
has a syntax error after the getAbsolutePath()

Syntax error on token ")", invalid ArgumentList

```
private void getDropboxIMGSize(Uri uri){
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.getPath()).getAbsolutePath(), options);
int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
}
```

Comment: Syntax error after getAbsolutePath() ......Syntax error on token ")", invalid ArgumentList......

Comment: You have missed ( before uri.getPath()

Answer (score 2):

If you extract your arguments into local variables, you'll be less likely to miss a parenthesis/include an extra one, and it'll be easier to read your code.

Before:

```
private void getDropboxIMGSize(Uri uri){
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.getPath()).getAbsolutePath(), options);
    int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
}
```

After:

```
private void getDropboxIMGSize(Uri uri){
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    String path = uri.getPath().getAbsolutePath();
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
}
```

Note, you've assigned `options.outHeight` and `options.outWidth` to local variables and then the method ends; you're not doing anything with these values.

Answer (score 1):

Do this way

```
public void getDropboxIMGSize(Uri uri) {
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getAbsolutePath(uri), o);
        int imageHeight = o.outHeight;
        int imageWidth = o.outWidth;
    }



public String getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: A content URI may come from different providers than the MediaStore. You'll get a null path in that case. You should never instantiate a `File` from an `Uri`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found it's solution at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16441573/1043882).You have to use

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File(uri.getPath()).getAbsolutePath(), options);
```

in your code instead of this:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.getPath()).getAbsolutePath(), options);
```