# Image margins are cut in the scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview, scale, margin, hidden

My android app **contains a map** that the user should ***scroll*** **horizontally** and **vertically** to see all of it.
I've used two horizontal and vertical scroll view, and the **image view** is in it.
But the problem is that, the picture **isn't shown completely** in the layout and a part of the top margin and left margin are hidden(**cut**).
so my question is:

1. How to show the picture completely in the scroll view without cutting the margins?[The problem is shown is this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlePz.jpg)
2. when I start the application **at first** the image in the scroll view is **not** scaled! and after a touch event gets bigger at its size.

code:

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay">

           <RelativeLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:orientation="vertical"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
               android:gravity="center">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"

                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    />

           </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: I also used linear layout instead of relative layout, but no changes occured!

Comment: Thanks for your help. It was helpful for me in the second problem I had,[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440863/can-i-get-image-file-width-and-height-from-uri-in-android) but again the first problem remains, I think one of the layout or scroll view causes this issue.

Comment: It looks like this is what you looking for
http://android-er.blogspot.in/2014/01/horizontal-vertical-scrollable-view.html

Comment: I tried the above link but extravagantly I get the same result! :( , I should say that my scroll view just scrolls to right and bottom though left and 
top stays fixed!?

Comment: scrolling to right goes infinitely..., I add some padding to the picture but didn't help because adding padding to the image manipulates its coordinates and the coordinates are vital in the application.

Comment: For map you don't have to add horizontal or vertical scroll views, cause map view or map fragment includes this by default.  From the image shared, it looks like there is a left and right padding or margin to the layout.  It may be defined in the style or check your root view.

Comment: Make the root view height and width match_parent

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the width and height of outer Relative Layout to match parent.
Your updated code should be like this:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay">

       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"

                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                />

       </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: unfortunately didn't help me, the error remains just described... also I tried fill_parent or other configs like minus margins but no changes occur.

Comment: the answer is wrong
Get the image width and height at realtime from bitmap you can do.
Set that width and height to the imageview programatically.

Comment: Adding pad to the inner linear layout improves the issue but the relative view damages the x coordinate though the y coordinate is correct.!